# Append Text to Richtextbox on Multiple Checked Node in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, richtextbox

I am working on Windows Form Application C#, When i check few treeview Nodes and on Button Click Event,  Text corresponding to each Treenode will be Append to richtextbox.

I had done similar thing while Select Treenode, Ex:

```
 if(treeView1.SelectedNode.Name == "First Node")
    this.richTextBox1.SelectedText = Firstline;

   elseif(treeView1.SelectedNode.Name == "Second Node")
    this.richTextBox1.SelectedText = Other Text;
```

But i need to do similar activity for Multiple Checked Node from my treeview (On Button press event).
Please help me

Comment: How do you select multiple nodes in `treeview`?

Comment: For selectnodes, i have worded with single nod selection, but for checked case, need multiple node selection. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your question is not clear . assuming 
you have winform with treeView1Control

```
       //populating treeView with dummy data
   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //set the check box true
            treeView1.CheckBoxes = true;
            TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode("Windows");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
            //
            // Another node following the first node.
            //
            treeNode = new TreeNode("Linux");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
            //
            // Create two child nodes and put them in an array.
            // ... Add the third node, and specify these as its children.
            //
            TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode("C#");
            TreeNode node3 = new TreeNode("VB.NET");
            TreeNode[] array = new TreeNode[] { node2, node3 };
            //
            // Final node.
            //
            treeNode = new TreeNode("Dot Net Perls", array);
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           string text = traverseTreeAngGetName(treeView1.Nodes);
           this.richTextBox1.SelectedText = text;

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// it will traverse all the tree Node from 1 to N Level. if Node is Checked then get
        /// the checked node name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tr"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string traverseTreeAngGetName(TreeNodeCollection tr){

            string str = "";

            foreach (TreeNode node in tr) {

                if (node.Checked) {
                    //here you can append any text on the base of current
                    str += node.Text + " - " ;
                }
                str += traverseTreeAngGetName(node.Nodes);
            }
            return str;
        }
```

Comment: Thnx Dude, Solved my problem.  :)